# Deleting allocated memory pointed by vector element crashes the program

Tags: c++, vector

I´m writing a dynamic program that will read a Oracle database metadata and build its structure in memory.

I´m facing a problem when freeing the memory created as `new` to hold data that Oracle sends to me. That structure is put inside a vector and runs fine (I can read and process it).

Here is my code (Database stuff was removed for focusing on the problem):

```
    struct OracleColumnStruct {
        std::string name;
        ub2 ociType;
        FieldType fieldType;
        int size;
        char *buffer;
        sb2  *indicator;
        OCIDefine *defineHandler;
    };

    std::vector<OracleColumnStruct> columns;

void AllocateColumns() 
{
        columnCount = ... // whatever from database

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {

            ociType = ... // whatever from database
            size = ... // whatever from database

            OracleColumnStruct data;
            data.name = "whatever";
            data.ociType = ociType;
            data.size = size;
            data.buffer = new char[size];
            data.indicator = new sb2;

            columns.push_back(data);
        }
}

void FreeColumns()
{
        for (auto &column : columns)
        {
            if (column.buffer)
                delete column.buffer; <<<- Crash here on 2nd interaction

            if (column.indicator)
                delete column.indicator;
        }
}
```

The crash message:

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#16497) at 0x00261940.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

When I need to free the structure, it frees the first element and on the second processing the vector seens to get lost.

Does deleting the pointer reference confuses the whole vector ? What shall be done in that case ?

Comment: Downvoters, please explain...

Comment: Your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. That's why it is being downvoted.

Comment: Additionally, complaining about being downvoted will itself get downvotes.

Comment: No complaining, but trying to learn from mistakes...

Comment: That indicates that something wrote past the end of `column.buffer`, and nothing detected it until you tried to free it. What is `column.buffer` used for?

Comment: Does "void AllocateColumns" compile?  Missing parenthesis of function?

Comment: @Mendes You used `vector` in one place, but why you didn't use it for `buffer` inside your structure, i.e. `std::vector<char> buffer;`? You have the tools right there to overcome this issue, but you refused (or didn't know) to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer` is allocated with `new[]`, so it must be freed using `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

`indicator` is allocated with `new`, so it must be freed using `delete` and not `delete[]`.

And there is no need to check for null, `delete` and `delete[]` already handle that for you:

```
void FreeColumns()
{
    for (auto &column : columns)
    {
        delete[] column.buffer;
        delete column.indicator;
    }
}
```

That being said, you should use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`, then you can get rid of `FreeColumns()` altogether and simply call `columns.clear()` when needed.

```
struct OracleColumnStruct {
    std::string name;
    ub2 ociType;
    FieldType fieldType;
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    std::unique_ptr<sb2> indicator;
    OCIDefine *defineHandler;
};

void AllocateColumns 
{
    columnCount = ... // whatever from database

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        ...
        OracleColumnStruct data;
        data.name = "whatever";
        data.ociType = ociType;
        data.buffer.resize(size);
        data.indicator.reset(new sb2);
        // or: data.indicator = std::make_unique<sb2>();

        columns.push_back(data);
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Remy, changing `delete` to `delete[]` did not solve the problem... There is something else going on here...

Comment: @Mendes then you are not managing your pointers correctly, or you are ovwrwritibg memory. But you have not shown enough code to diagnose one way or the other. This is why you should avoid using raw pointers, use containers instead and let C++ manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you've allocated something with new in its array form

```
char* buffer = new char[size];
```

then you should use the array form of delete for deletion

```
delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: That  change from `delete` to `delete[]` did not solve the problem... There is something else going on here...